# how to color alternate rows in multiple tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to color alternate rows in multiple tables. It's like table inside table. I want to color alternate rows of inner table.
   Tables are not fixed, it s dynamically generated by process. Rows are also not fixed.
Kindly help

```
function update_rows(){
    $("table#id2 tr:even").css("background-color", "#DEB887");
    $("table#id2 tr:odd").css("background-color", "");
}
```

Comment: it can be done in css. do you really need Javascript?

Comment: (1) Please show [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and some code. (2) Are you allowed to use a library like JQuery or is it supposed to be done only with javascript? This could even be done only with CSS, but you haven't specified your requirement.

Answer (score 5):

**Way 1:**

*CSS*

```
tr.alt td {background-color: #e6EEEE;}
```

*Jquery*

```
$("tr:odd").addClass("alt");​
```

**Way 2:**

*Jquery*

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "#eeeeee");
$("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#ffffff");
```

**Update:**
Live [jsFiddle example1](http://jsfiddle.net/yxUH4/), [jsFiddle example2](http://jsfiddle.net/JdsfL/).

Answer (score 1):

it can be done very easily using jquery

```
$("tr:even").css("background-color", "#bbbbff");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try any of below

```
$("div table").each(function (i) { $(this).find("tr:not(first)+tr:even").addClass("even"); });
```

or

```
$("div table tr:not(first)+tr:even").addClass("even");
```

both have small difference, in second one sometime you will find that odd/even is not correctly handled for subsequent tables if previous tables number of rows are odd/even

Answer (score 0):

CSS only (not in older browsers):

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {
 /** your styling **/
}
```